# Advanced installer: query result is not stored in property

Tags: advanced-installer

I want to run a query inside advanced installer and use its result in final stages of installation.
The scenario is like this:
In start of setup, using a query I insert a record in log table like this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @UML_ID int
EXEC    @return_value = [Common].[UML_Insert_WebServiceInstaller]
        @UML_ToVersion = '$VERSION$',
        @UML_UpdateType = 1,
        @UML_ID = @UML_ID OUTPUT

SELECT @UML_ID AS UML_ID_PROP
```

Then at the end of installation I should update record given with returned as UML_ID_PROP.

I have defined my query to store its result in `UML_ID_PROP` like this:

[image]

And then I want to show the result stored in `UML_ID_PROP` in combobox but it does not show up and its default value is displayed only.

[image]

And here is the configuration for property `UML_ID_PROP`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the property during **Install Execution** Stage. It's a Windows Installer limitation that property values cannot pass from **Install Execution Stage** to **Wizard Dialogs Stage**.

The workaround you have is to set the property through a custom action scheduled in the **Wizard Dialogs Stage**.

As I can see, you are trying to get the result of an SQL Query in a property and display that property on the **ExitDialog**. Note that you can easily execute the SQL Query on the Wizard Dialogs Stage, for details please check the [Set MSI properties from SQL queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rakMD115A6o) video.

Check the [Windows Installer Custom Actions](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions.html) article for a better understanding of how custom actions/ standard actions are executed in the MSI.